# AJAX request from iframe, why is the origin the parent's URL?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, cors

I have a website that I am loading an iframe in. The iframe is on a different subdomain than the website itself. Let's say the website is on `portal.domain.com` and the iframe is on `iframe.domain.com`. I need to make requests to `iframe.domain.com` from `portal.domain.com` and I was hoping to use this iframe to make those requests.

I created the iframe like this:

```
// On portal.domain.com
document.domain = "domain.com";
var iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
iframe.contentWindow.onIframeLoad = function() {
    iframe.contentWindow.makeRequest();
}

var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
        'var s = document.createElement(\'script\');' + 
        's.onload = onIframeLoad;' +
        'document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(s).src=\'' + "iframe.domain.com/content.js" + '\'">');
doc.close();
```

The script loaded in the iframe looks like this:

```
// iframe.domain.com/content.js
document.domain = "domain.com"

function makeRequest() {
  // AJAX call here
}
```

The AJAX call is made, but the origin gets set to `portal.domain.com`. This causes the cookies not to be sent and for the browser to block the response due to its CORS policy. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why aren't you using JSONP?

Comment: @GuyT — Why would anyone use JSONP in 2016? We have CORS now.

Comment: @Quentin I agree.. The OP has first to give the exact reason why this is necessary before we can give any good advice.

Comment: I'm not using JSONP because private data is involved. I'm not using CORS because it creates a weird dependency structure. E.g. `portal.domain.com` depends on `iframe.domain.com`, but, if I use CORS, `iframe.domain.com` must also know `portal.domain.com` exists. Additionally, the CORS implementation for CXF (which is what I'm using) isn't great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

You can not.  Doing that is actually cross-domain execution, which is a huge security risk. So most of modern browsers will track you originating entry point to you script and see that it was loaded from different domain.

If you want to do it :

1. Load JavaScript from iFrame domain
2. Define an object (lets’ say window.iframeparams)
3. Populate it
4. Call “send” on the JavaScript code, loaded from iframe domain

It is actually the same proceeding as google analytics or any other tracking software

Edit :

Again, **browsers will track origin of call**. So, your method by creating dynamic iFrame will not work (Or may be on ie6)

Comment: Oh I see my error. I need to set the iframe `src` field to something belonging to `iframe.domain.com`. Thanks!

Comment: Exact ! It should be on the same domain as a call. But still not sure it will work with dynamic iFrame creation

Comment: Just tested it. This does work with a programmatically created iframe. You can also use `iframe.onload` to trigger a function when the iframe finishes loading (instead of the weird hack I used in the post).

Comment: Can u please present a working code for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is restricted in most browser because of the "Same-Origin" policy. You can read more about this, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy.

There are ways to work around this limitation, using technologies such as JSONP or html5 messaging.

You may want to look at similar questions and their answers, here:

- [SO: Making ajax calls from inside of an iframe with different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183828/making-ajax-calls-from-inside-of-an-iframe-with-different-domain)
- [SO: Ajax inside iframe not working against same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455774/ajax-inside-iframe-not-working-against-same-server)

**Edit:** There is also a lengthy list of ways to circumvent the same-origin policy, here: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: That page is not found. The reason I'm using an iframe is because it is supposed to circumvent same-origin-policy. This doesn't explain why the origin is not the domain of the iframe.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in the url